# Allow customers to add product in to cart only one time?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I need some help customizing my BigCommerce store.

After a product is added to the cart, I want the "Add to Cart" button for that product to change and say "Already in Cart".

Also, I only want the user to be able to add a product one time into his/her cart.

Here is button code:

```
<div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideActionAdd%%;">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductURL%%"><input  id="btnCopy" class="btn icon-%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" type="button" value="Add to cart"  onclick="return change(this);" /></a>
    </div>
```

Can you please give me some suggestions on how to achieve this? 
My store URL is: https://deepak-diwan-s-store.mybigcommerce.com

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and where you are running into issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing out the specific code, you can follow these general steps to achieve what you are seeking:

1. Upon product page load, have a JS script do the following: 
   a. Grab the SKU from the current product page. 
   b. Perform an Ajax GET request to the cart page, and load the cart contents. 
   c. If the cart contents `:contains` the product SKU from step A, then the product is in cart. 
   d. If product is in cart, then change the button text and disable it. 
   e. Else if product not already in cart, do nothing.

As a followup to your comment, add a click handler to the button to check if the customer should be unable to add the product to the cart again.

```
$('#id_of_button_here').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //Stop button from adding product to cart temporarily. 
  // Read the button value to see if it equals 'INCART'
  if ($(this).val() === 'INCART') {
    alert('This product has already been added to the cart. You may not add it again');
    return false;
  } else {
    $(this).click(); //Click the button to proceed with normal operations.
  }
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

      function change( el )
{
    if ( el.value === "Add to cart" )
        el.value = "INCART";
   else
        el.value = "INCART";
}
</script>

i have to use this script its allow to change add to cart text from add to cart to INCART but still allow customer to add to cart again .
please add your code if you modify it for solution

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Changing the button text is purely visual, I'm sure you don't expect it to also prevent it from adding to the cart again. I've added some code that may help, hope it gets the point across.

Comment: just little bit confused please check it you guide me the right way    <input  id="btnCopy" class="btn icon-%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" type="button" value="Add to cart"  onclick="return change(this);" />  this is input i have used for button.please help little more you are too close @suhdo

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj please add this code to your original question, it makes it easier to read.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj I have modified my code, to read the button Value (`<button value="value">...</button>`), rather than the Button Text (`<button> Button Text </button>`

Comment: Your code is working for only one product and also after remove product from cart it's still showing an alert that product already into cart . @suhdo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116286/discussion-between-raj-kumar-bhardwaj-and-suhdo).

Comment: I'm sorry @RajKumarBhardwaj but you need to show more effort and spend some more time in thought on this issue. I can't write the entire code out, which is especially unfair if you are getting paid to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your 'ADD TO CART' button when user click it and on page load jquery find all class and change its text.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you explain jquery code please ?

Comment: This might help you: [Help Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rietykity/8z4qLyfh/)

Comment: I checked your profile and you are good at Front-End development and knows a lot. You should not ask these silly simple logical question over here.